# Stuck calculating the derivative of $f(x)=\log_{10}{\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{5-x^2}}}$.

Tags: derivatives

I have to calculate the derivative of this:

$$f(x)=\log_{10}{\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{5-x^2}}}$$

But I'm stuck. This is the point where I have arrived:

$$f'(x) = \frac{(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})(\sqrt{5-x^2})+x^2}{x(\ln 10)(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})(\sqrt{5-x^2})}$$

How can I simplify? I didn't include all the passages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding a derivative with $\log$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2748592/finding-a-derivative-with-log)

Answer (score 1):

You have $\frac{(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})(\sqrt{5-x^2})+x^2}{x(\ln 10)(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})(\sqrt{5-x^2})}$

splitting into 2 fractions gives ;

$\frac{(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})(\sqrt{5-x^2})}{x(\ln 10)(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})(\sqrt{5-x^2})}+\frac{x^2}{x(\ln 10)(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})(\sqrt{5-x^2})}$

$=\frac1{x(\ln(10))}+\frac{x}{(\ln 10)(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})(\sqrt{5-x^2})}$

$ = \frac1{x(\ln(10))}+\frac{10^y}{\ln(10)(\sqrt{5-x^2})}$

Answer (score 0):

Start with the fact that your function

$$f(x) = \log_{10} (x) - \log_{10}(1+\sqrt{5-x^2}).$$

Comment: I've already did that at the beginning to calculate the derivative

Comment: That's my point.

Answer (score 0):

Since the denominator is positive (when it's defined, that is, for $-\sqrt5\le x\le \sqrt5 $), the function is only defined for $0<x\le \sqrt5 $, so you can write it as
$$
f(x)=\log_{10}x-\log_{10}(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})
$$
which should simplify the computation very much. Recall that the derivative of $\log_{10}{x}$ is
$$
\frac{1}{x\log10}
$$
(natural logarithm, write it ln if you prefer) and apply the chain rule.

You will get
$$
\frac{1}{\log10}\left(
\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{5-x^2}}\frac{-x}{\sqrt{5-x^2}}
\right)
$$
Then it's just simplifications, if you really want to do more than that:
$$
\frac{1}{\log10}\frac{\sqrt{5-x^2}+5-x^2+x^2}{x\sqrt{5-x^2}(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})}
=
\frac{1}{\log10}\frac{\sqrt{5-x^2}+5}{x\sqrt{5-x^2}(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})}
$$
The derivative doesn't exist at $x= \sqrt5 $.

Answer (score 0):

The first derivative is given by $$f'(x)= \left(  \left( 1+\sqrt {5-{x}^{2}} \right) ^{-1}+{\frac {{x}^{2}}{
 \left( 1+\sqrt {5-{x}^{2}} \right) ^{2}\sqrt {5-{x}^{2}}}} \right) 
 \left( 1+\sqrt {5-{x}^{2}} \right) {x}^{-1} \left( \ln  \left( 10
 \right)  \right) ^{-1}
$$ and can be simplified to
$$f'(x)={\frac {\sqrt {5-{x}^{2}}+5}{x\ln  \left( 10 \right)  \left( 1+\sqrt {
5-{x}^{2}} \right) \sqrt {5-{x}^{2}}}}
$$